# C - How to arrange the first number of a couple in ascending order?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

My homework is: Write a function that gets an array with integers. `N * 2 = the size` of the array since `N = how many couples you will scan`. The array includes couples of numbers. I need to print the numbers where the numbers on a plural index are in ascending order.

Example:

```
Input: 4, -6, 2, 10, 3, 0, 1, 9
Ouput: 1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 0, 4, -6 
With N = 4.
```

If I set`N = 4`, it lets me scan only 4 numbers, not 8. Why is that? And it even prints weird numbers after the 4th scanned number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int n, sz1, sz2;
int i, j, cs, cs2;
printf("Enter the value of n:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
int array[2*n];
printf("Enter the numbers in the array:\n");
for(i=0; i<2*n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    i++;
}
for(i=0; i<2*n; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<2*n; j++)
    {
        if(array[i]>array[j] && i%2==0 )
        {
            cs=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=cs;
            cs2=array[i+1];
            array[i+1]=array[j+1];
            array[j+1]=cs2;
        }
    }
}
for(i=0; i<n*2; i++)
    printf("%d  %d\n", array[i], array[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to print 2 numbers at a time, you need to increment `i` by 2 in the loop, and use indices `i` and `i+1`.

Comment: Remove `i++` from inside the loop.

Comment: @Dora  Are the name Dora and Russian Darja the same name?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the first loop, you shouldn't be doing `i++`, as you're already doing it in the `for` clause. By doing it the way you're doing, at each loop, `i` gets incremented twice, giving you half the loops.

Also, when you try to read from the array every other element was not set, so it may contain garbage data.

Answer (score 1):

We beginners should help each other.:)

These loops

```
for(i=0; i<2*n; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<2*n; j++)
    {
        if(array[i]>array[j] && i%2==0 )
        {
            cs=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=cs;
            cs2=array[i+1];
            array[i+1]=array[j+1];
            array[j+1]=cs2;
        }
    }
}
```

do not make sense even if you will follow the advice of **@Federico klez Culloca** .

Consider the case when `n` is equal to 1. When for your demonstrative array you will get

```
4 -6 // 2 10 3 0 1 9
-6 2 // 4 10 3 0 1 9
```

that is there is at least an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

If I have understood the assignment correctly then you could use the standard C function `qsort` declared in header `<stdlib.h>` instead of writing your own implementation of the bubble sort as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp_pair(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const int *lhs = (const int *)p;
    const int *rhs = (const int *)q;

    return (*rhs < *lhs) - (*lhs < *rhs);
}

int main( void )
{
    const size_t n = 4;
    int a[2 * n] = { 4, -6, 2, 10, 3, 0, 1, 9 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    qsort(a, n, sizeof(int[2]), cmp_pair);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The program output is

```
4 -6 2 10 3 0 1 9
1 9 2 10 3 0 4 -6
```

Or if to use an implementation of the bubble sort then the loops can look as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const size_t n = 4;
    int a[2 * n] = { 4, -6, 2, 10, 3, 0, 1, 9 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    for ( size_t m = n, last = n; !( m < 2 ); m = last )
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 1; i < m ; i++ )
        {
            if ( a[2 *i] < a[2 * ( i - 1)] )
            {
                int tmp[2] = { a[2 * i], a[2 * i + 1] };
                a[2 * i] = a[2 * (i - 1)];
                a[2 * i + 1] = a[2 * (i - 1) + 1];
                a[2 * (i - 1)] = tmp[0];
                a[2 * (i - 1) + 1] = tmp[1];
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The output will be the same as it is shown above.

```
4 -6 2 10 3 0 1 9
1 9 2 10 3 0 4 -6
```

All you need to write yourself is to write the code that inputs the value of the variable `n` and fill the array with values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution attempt. I used structs to contain the number pairs. I also called my functions from main().

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct pairs{
  int numA;
  int numB;
}num_pair;

num_pair* create_num_pair_array(num_pair*, int);
void sort_pairs(num_pair*, int);
void print_num_pairs(num_pair*, int);

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter the number of pairs, n:\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  num_pair array[n];
  create_num_pair_array(array, n);
  sort_pairs(array, n);
  print_num_pairs(array, n);
  return 0;
}

num_pair* create_num_pair_array(num_pair* array, int arr_size)
{
  int i;
  printf("Enter the number pairs:\n");
  for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
    printf("Enter first number for number pair %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i].numA);
    printf("Enter second number for number pair %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i].numB);
  }
  return array;
}

void sort_pairs(num_pair* array, int arr_size)
{
  int i, j;
  num_pair temp;
  temp.numA = 0;
  temp.numB = 0; 
  for(i = 0; i < (arr_size - 1); i++){
    for(j = 0; j < arr_size - i - 1; j++){
      if(array[j].numA > array[j+1].numA){
      temp.numA = array[j].numA;
      temp.numB = array[j].numB;
      array[j] = array[j+1];
      array[j+1].numA = temp.numA;
      array[j+1].numB = temp.numB; 
      }
    }
  }
}

void print_num_pairs(num_pair* array, int arr_size)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
    printf("%d %d\n", array[i].numA, array[i].numB);
  }
}
```